# How to Add where clause on array key of any serilized field for select data?

Tags: php

I am add where clause on the key of serialized array field (I am using PHP/MySQL).
 But SQL not working and display error.

**Display Error is:** `"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''Employer'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in...."`

**Serilized array is**:(which is saved inside database table)  `a:2:{s:8:"Employer";s:9:"sanjayEMP";s:7:"Section";s:10:"production";}`

**My CodeIgniter SQL is:**

```
   $this->db->select("*");
   $this->db->select("emplyee_details");
   $this->db->where("status",1);
   $this->db->where("ValueDetails","REGEXP '.*"Employer";s:[0-9]+:"jack".*'");
   $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Here,
 
**ValueDetails** is a field of serialized array in database table. And
**Employer** is the array key of the serilized field in the database table.

If anyone has a great idea how to add where clause on array key of any specialized field. Please give me suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: The best way to do this should be to save the these informations in others columns, like employer_name and section. Requesting on it would be easier and more optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this line should be like this, you ommited backslashes to escape double quotes, and misplaced the REGEXP keyword:

```
$this->db->where("ValueDetails REGEXP",".*\"Employer\";s:[0-9]+:\"jack\".*");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but after the addition of backslash, the problem was not solved.

Comment: Record is available in the database table, but the output from SQL is empty. 
When I removed the where condition, then again the record is displayed.

Comment: I edtited my answer because in documentation where operators are placed in the first argument. Can you try it? https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: Thanks, @Damien, now working properly when operators are placed in the first argument.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Can you please validate this answer? Thanks!